# Angular [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider with customize directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a little issue by using a customize directive within the template field of UI-Bootstrap modal directive.

My aim is send data to modal via resolve attribute and re-use these resolved parameters inside the controller of my own directive.

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap']);

app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal', function($scope, $modal) {
  $scope.openModal = function () {
    var popup = $modal.open({
            template: '<my-modal></my-modal>',
            resolve : {
                mydata : function() {
                    return 42;
                }
            }
        });
  };
}]);

app.controller('ModalController', ['$scope', 'mydata', function($scope, mydata) {
  //The error is in this directive controller
  $scope.mydata = mydata;
}]);

app.directive('myModal', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl : 'mymodal.html',
    controller : 'ModalController',
    replace: true
  };
});
```

Maybe I proceed in the wrong way.

Any suggest to make this code functionnal ?

http://plnkr.co/edit/RND2Jju79aOFlfQGnGN8?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolve parameters are only injected to the controller defined in the `$modal.open` config parameters, but you want to inject it to the directive controller. That will not work. Imagine you would use the `myModal` directive somewhere else, there wouldn't be a `myData` object that could be used.

But i don't realy see, what you need the directive for. You could go much easier this way:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', '$modal',
  function($scope, $modal) {
    $scope.openModal = function() {
      var popup = $modal.open({
        templateUrl: 'mymodal.html',
        controller: 'ModalController',
        resolve: {
          mydata: function() {
            return 42;
          }
        }
      });
    };
  }
]);

// Here the mydata of your resolves will be injected!
app.controller('ModalController', ['$scope', 'mydata',
  function($scope, mydata) {
    $scope.mydata = mydata
  }
]);
```

Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/bIhiwRjkUFb4oUy9Wn8w?p=preview

Comment: This is certainly the "correct" way to use $modal.  Since you were using a directive, I think you might have looking to make a reusable component that you use throughout your app without having to provide the controller / template every time.  If that's the case, take a look at my answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/30530600/61604

Answer (score 0):

you need to provide an Object "mydata". Ensure, that you have a correct implemented factory which provides your myData Object. If you had done that, you can "inject" your myData Object where ever you want to.

```
yourApp.MyDataFactory = function () {
   var myData = {i: "am", an: "object"};
   return myData;
}
```

this would provide an "myData" Object

Comment: resolve in $model does this for you, so it can be injected into the modal's controller.  You dont need to service a factory / service.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with the directive, but if you are trying to provide a generic way to invoke the $model, that you can then use from many places in your app, you may be better off to wrap $model with a service. Than you can then call from other places in your app.

I forked and modified your plunkr to work this way:  http://plnkr.co/edit/0CShbYNNWNC9SiuLDVw3?p=preview

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', ['$scope', 'modalSvc', function($scope, modalSvc) {
  var mydata = {
    value1: 42
  };

  $scope.openModal = function () {
    modalSvc.open(mydata);
  };
}]);

app.factory('modalSvc', ['$modal', function ($modal) {

  var open = function (mydata) {
      var modalInstance,
          modalConfig = {
              controller: 'ModalController',
              resolve: {
                  mydata: function () {
                      return mydata;
                  }
              },
              templateUrl: 'mymodal.html'
          };

      modalInstance = $modal.open(modalConfig);

      return modalInstance;
  };

  return {
      open: open
  };

}]);
```

Also, I changed mydata to be an object, rather than '42', as I am sure you will have other data to pass in.  the markup was updated accouringly:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  BODY {{mydata.value1}}
</div>
```

Doing it this way, the resolve property works, and you can get your data.

As for the other answers mentioning you must define `mydata`, the resolve property passed into $model does this for you, so it can be injected into the modal's controller (`ModalController`), like you have done.